# testing directive throw exception if attr is undefined

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, karma-runner

I have an angularjs directive that needs a resource attr to be defined in order to make some logic. The next is a minimal definition for it:

```
angular.module('myAppName')
    .directive('loadObjects', loadObjects);

function loadObjects($window) {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<md-content class="md-whiteframe-z4" layout-padding></md-content>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            if (angular.isUndefined(attrs.resource)) {
                throw 'resource attr is mandatory';
            }
        }
    };
    return directive;
}
```

then in my tests, I'm trying to test that an invalid template throw the exception.

```
describe('LoadObjects directive', function() {
    beforeEach(module('myAppName'));

    it('should throw an error if resource attr is not defined', inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
        var scope = $rootScope.$new();
        var elem = angular.element('<load-objects></load-objects>');
        expect(function() { $compile(elem)(scope); }).toThrow('resource attr is mandatory');
    }));
});
```

But I'm getting the next err:

```
Expected function to throw 'resource attr is mandatory', but it threw TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$window.Raven.captureMessage')
```

Also I've tried to use that directive in a template and I can see the exception there in the javascript console.

Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks for reading.

**Edit**

After that, I'm trying to use:

```
beforeEach(module('myAppName', function($provide, $injector) {
    $provide.constant('DEBUG', true);
    console.log($injector.get('DEBUG')); // it prints true
}));
```

Inside the beforeEach, the DEBUG is altered, but it does not work.

In order to my test becomes successfull, I need `DEBUG=true`, my second question: What's wrong with this approach?

Comment: It reads like you're trying to call a non-existing object's member (`'undefined' is not an object`), which makes it not directly related to the error you're trying to throw. Does the console error narrow it down to a line?

Comment: This is the error message printed in the console: `Raven: Message  resource attr is mandatory Object { exception: "resource attr is mandatory", cause: "<load-objects>" } angular.js:12416:18`. It works as expected, but in testing,  I think raven is capturing the exception (since I did not define a the `resource` attr) before the link function throw the exception.

Comment: Did you include Raven in the karma test runner config? I dunno how Raven works...

Comment: Yep, raven is included in the karma.conf.js. I just got it, In my cofig block, I use `$ravenProvider.development(DEBUG);`, and I've defined a `DEBUG` as an angular constant. So, when `DEBUG` is false, the error is captured by raven.

Comment: I think I'd try to run it in a browser and put a break point near the `raven.captureMessage` statement to see if it exists on the `$window` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's my final approach:

As I've said my test will pass if I configure:

```
$ravenProvider.development(DEBUG); // with DEBUG=true
```

but since:

```
beforeEach(module('myAppName', function($provide, $injector) {
    $provide.constant('DEBUG', true);
    console.log($injector.get('DEBUG')); // it prints true
}));
```

does not work, I decide to alter directly the value passed to raven:

```
beforeEach(module('myAppName', function($ravenProvider) {
    $ravenProvider.development(true);
}));
```

and that's it it works now.